# how to access the child node from ul list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about jquery dom.

let say I have this jsp code.

```
<c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList }" varStatus="status">

    <ul class="shList" id="shList">
        <li class="fl">
            <ul class="top">
                <li>${ result.appSn}</li>
                <li>${result.mkType }</li>
                <li>${result.clasType }</li>
                <li>${result.appUseGrade }</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="bottom">
                <p class="fl">- ${result.appNm}</p>
                <span class="fr">${result.inputDt}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="sliding">
                paragraph


            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fr"><img src="${result.appLeaderImg}" alt="" width="60" height="60" /></li>
    </ul>

</c:forEach>
```

and I want to toggle the sliding when I click the specific UL.
and I want to access the div class ="sliding"

Here is my jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#shList li").click(function(){
        console.log("chList Clicked");
        console.log($(this).children().eq(1));
        console.log($(this).children().eq(2));
        console.log($(this).next());
        console.log($(this).next().next());
        $(".sliding p").toggle();
    });
});
```

Im not sure how to access the paragraph sliding.

Comment: `$(this).find(".sliding")`

Comment: Probably worth noting that your looping and not taking into account elements will have duplicate IDs thus creating invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).find()` to search for a selector inside the `li` that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#shList li").click(function(){
        console.log("chList Clicked");
        console.log($(this).children().eq(1));
        console.log($(this).children().eq(2));
        console.log($(this).next());
        console.log($(this).next().next());
        $(this).find(".sliding p").toggle();
    });
});
```

You should probably also make the original selector more specific: `$("#shlist li.fl")`. Otherwise it will be used for the `.fr` element and the `<li>` inside `ul.top`.